# AngularJS ui-bootstrap timepicker automatically set current time even $scope.dateRemind is null

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

my problem: i use a date and timepicker from ui-bootstrap ([see here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/))
there 2 different ways i fill these date and timepicker:
first: i have a remindDate, so there will be the date and time from database. works fine

2nd: i dont have a remindDate, so i get null from db, so the date is empty, but the time will be set to current, not empty or 00:00.

i dont know why its set to current time

my view:

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
                <p class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="noticeRemind" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="notice.dateRemind" is-open="opened" min-date="minDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" close-text="Schlie&szlig;en" />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                        </button></span>
                </p>
                <timepicker ng-model="notice.dateRemind" name="timePicker" hour-step="1" minute-step="15" show-meridian="false"></timepicker>
                <br>
                <alert ng-hide="dateValid(notice.dateRemind)" type="danger">
                    Erinnerung muss in der Zukunft liegen.
                </alert>
            </div>
```

my controller:

```
myApp.controller("ModalController", function($scope, $modalInstance, data, ProjectFactory) {


// NOTIZ
$scope.noticeID = data.noticeID;
$scope.notice = angular.copy(data.notice);  <---- here the date/time is set null if no date/time
$scope.error = false;

$scope.closeModal = function() {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};

/**
 * DATE funktionen
 *
 */
$scope.dateValid = function(date) {
    if (date === null) {
        return true;
    }
    if (date < new Date()) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;

};

$scope.today = function() {
    $scope.dt = new Date();
};

$scope.clear = function() {
    $scope.dt = null;
};

// Disable sunday selection
$scope.disabled = function(date, mode) {
    return (mode === 'day' && date.getDay() === 0 );
};

$scope.toggleMin = function() {
    $scope.minDate = $scope.minDate ? null : new Date();
};
$scope.toggleMin();

$scope.open = function($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();

    $scope.opened = true;
};

$scope.format = "dd.MM.yyyy";
});
```

any ideas??
i already tried to set the notice.dateRemind.setHours(0) and notice.dateRemind.setMinuit(0) but its null so i got exception

HAPPY NEW YEAR

Comment: null sets to current date-time, variable should be undefined. I know its little weird, but thats the way it is.

Comment: in data.notice, change date-time to undefined , if null

Comment: thx for fast answer.now its undefined, but still current time.

Comment: can you setup a plunker in that case

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/kYlzox7cipyJL4EyNmjK?p=preview

Comment: nopes, i checked it, what you say seems to be the default behavior. what you can do though is, rather than setting the value to null, set it to 00:00, that would be as good as null :), I know this is a  workaround rather than solution

Comment: you can set `notice.dateRemind = (new Date()).getDate()` which will contain time as zero

Comment: this would be a solution, but my date and timepicker use the same scope model. and it has to be possible to save the form without any date. but thank you... i will search for a different way

Comment: does server side support just time without date?? I doubt.

Comment: if i save my form without a date, my model is null, even if there is there current time in my timepicker